# Laravel function returns null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have made a function to use within my Laravel project.

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    $customer = DB::table('customer')
    ->where('email', $user->mail)
    ->get();

    die($customer);
```

But somehow the $customer stays empty all the time.

Every other query I made so far works except this one. I tried to replace get() with first() but no result. with get() the only thing I get is an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you actually have a record to query.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line:

```
die($customer);
```

to

```
dd($customer);
```

`dd` means `die` and `dump`. In your code, you are not dumping object.